# Best way to do an A-Z list in Django?

Tags: django

I've been hunting around and Googling for examples, but I can't see an obvious best way to do an A-Z list of entries in Django.

I have around 2,000 placenames in a db. Rather than display them all on the same page, I'd like to have tabs or hyperlinks and an A-Z list of names.

Something like [this A-Z list](http://www.direct.gov.uk/en/Dl1/Directories/A-ZOfCentralGovernment/index.htm). Bonus points if it's possible to create a similar page which allows users to page through by a db field, rather than A-Z.

Surely I don't need to roll my own code for this in Django - it must be a common problem. Can anyone provide any good examples, or even a Django app to make this straightforward?

Comment: It's a common problem but will be handled differently in different locales, which may be why it isn't in the Django core.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to filter your queryset according to what the user has selected:

Case insensitive:

```
Entry.objects.filter(field__istartswith='a')
```

Case sensitive:

```
Entry.objects.filter(field__startswith='A')
```

Answer (score 1):

Alphabetical pagination might also be useful to you -- see something like https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1364/